# C# Winforms databinding

Tags: c#, winforms

Quick question:

I have an usercontrol and I am passing a business object to it in order to be edited and saved. The usercontrol is not destroyed after save, instead it is hidden until next businessobject is passed to it.

The problem is I can't refresh the data in the controls unless I'm doing this:

```
UsernameTextEdit.DataBindings.Clear();
UsernameTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entityBo, "Username", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
LastNameTextEdit.DataBindings.Clear();
LastNameTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entityBo, "LastName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
FirstNameTextEdit.DataBindings.Clear();
FirstNameTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entityBo, "FirstName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Not sure if I'm doing it right. It *has* to be a better way, I believe. What I actually need is some sort of

```
UsernameTextEdit.DataBindings.Refresh()
```

or something similar, because the controls are already bound to the businessobject properties, all I need is to make them read the damn values again.

Is there such thing? Am I missing something?

Thank you

==============================

I am posting the businessobject model, although I can't fathom how this would help, because it works properly *first time*

```
namespace ServiceManager.Bll.Model
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class UsersBo : BaseBo
    {
        [Display(Name = "Nume utilizator")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Numele de utilizator este obligatoriu.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Numele de utilizator nu poate depăși 100 de caractere.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Parola")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Parola este obligatorie.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Parola nu poate depăși 100 de caractere")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prenume")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prenumele este obligatoriu")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Prenumele nu poate depăși 100 de caractere")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nume")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Numele este obligatoriu.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Numele nu poate depăși 100 de caractere.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Adresa e-mail nu poate depăși 100 de caractere")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Telefon")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Numărul de telefon nu poate depăși 50 de caractere")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Activ")]
        public bool IsActiv { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

===========================
Later edit:

Well, you know what happens when you explain your problem to someone and figure it out while you're talking?

In my case was *"hey, where the heck I'm setting the BindingSource's datasource? oh, yea, it was set in designer. Hmmmm... what if I'm setting it again instead dropping and adding bindings back?"* and guess what, works.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Post your model code. Your model should be `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: There is no evidence in the code you posted that your model object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the older convention of having `XXXChanged` events for each property. One or the other would be required in order for the target of the binding to be updated when the source value changes. If that is not enough for you to see the problem, you need to fix the question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The question seem to be unrelated to individual property bindings. Looks like OP is asking how to rebind to a different object instance.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough, sorry. I am passing a different object every time, and I need the controls to reflect the new values. I am not changing the current businessobject, so INotifyPropertyChanged won't help, I believe. Instead, I'm passing a completely new BO and in form_load I need the controls to show the values of that object's properties.

Comment: @IvanStoev: exactly, thanks for spotting it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your bindings are tied to a concrete instance, thus has to be recreated anytime the instance is changed.

In order to allow one time data binding setup, you need some indirection - it could be a special object with business object being a selectable property (e.g. something like `public UsersBo Current { get; set; }`, so you bind to that object through nested bindings like "Current.Name" etc., or use `BindingSource` component for that purpose as follows.

Start by adding `BindingSource` component field to your class:

```
private BindingSource bindingSource;
```

Then perform one time data binding setup (in constructor or load event):

```
bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(UsersBo); // to allow binding w/o actual object
// statically bind the controls to the binding source
UsernameTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bindingSource, "Username", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
LastNameTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bindingSource, "LastName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
FirstNameTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bindingSource, "FirstName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Basically replace `entityBo` with `bindingSource`. Now anytime you need to select a different object (including the initial), you can simply do

```
bindingSource.DataSource = entityBo;
```

and that's it - the data binding infrastructure wil take care for the rest.

Comment: Thank you. Very good and very clear answer, much appreciated.